# MacOS update stuck in infinite loop

Tags: software-update, macos

My MacBook Pro is acting weird, so I decided to try an advertised update and reboot.  The Update window says I've got two available updates, and that I should restart now. I click that, it gives me two EULAs to agree to, and then I get the same dialog back again. I can repeat that apparently any number of times. To be clear, no apparent update happens, and the system does not reboot.

Is there some common thing I can do to make it actually do the update?

Comment: Have you manually restarted the machine?

Comment: I rebooted it via the "Restart" option, a surprisingly slow process, and the update seems to have happened. I'll leave the question open in case anybody has other ideas.

Comment: @Ezekiel I just thought it was pretty odd that the System Update tool was offering me a way to restart the machine, but it completely didn't work.

Comment: It should work, but sometimes things go awry, and restarting the computer "normally" can sort out whatever it was.

Comment: @Ezekiel right, clearly. I'm relatively new to MacOS from many years of Linux and I don't know how many times I've heard "you really should try it, everything just works" :)  Overall I find it extremely nice however. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it's all sorted